# Check script finish time

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I have example below:

```
// start time
// make mysql query here

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) // for loop
{
// make dig lookup here

   if (domain found){
    // Update database
    }

}

if (time <= 60 sec)// check current finishing time and compare
{
// make my sql update
}
```

What I want to do is to check how many seconds the time is after the loop and then if the time taken to finish the for loop is less than 60 sec than run the mysql update. If you don't understand me, you can ask me. I'm sorry for the language. I'm not good with English and I wasn't sure if this thing is possible to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$time1 = time();
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){ // for loop

    // make dig lookup here

}
$time2 = time();

if (($time2 - $time1) < 60){

    // make my sql update

}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$start = microtime(true);

[...]

$end = microtime(true);

if (($end - $start) < 60) {

}
```

Comment: @Jleagle: only if you want to check for 60,000 seconds. From the manual: `If get_as_float is set to TRUE, then microtime() returns a float, which represents the current time in seconds since the Unix epoch`

Answer (score 1):

First, remember to close your connections.

Anyway, the `microtime` solution given by @webbiedave is good, but i've had some weird experiences (negative results mostly).

The [Advanced PHP Debugger](http://mx.php.net/apd) has gave me better results.

**How to use it:**

1.First line of your script

```
<?php
  // In the First line of your script
  apd_set_pprof_trace();
  // The rest of your code here
?>
```

2.Run the script. This file will be generated: `apd.dumpdir/pprof_pid.ext`

3.Display the data with `pprofp`

```
bash-2.05b$ pprofp -R /tmp/pprof.22141.0
```

Comment: Do you have example code with using the `APD`? I would be interested to see it and may give a +1 for it as well.

Comment: I do not think that is what he is asking for. He wants this done automatically, not have to go in, look at the file, and then run his updates manually. I think in this instance, the `microtime` is the way to go and this is not a spot for the APD.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But i don't think it's a good idea to execute some action given a process time. Just a lock in the table involved will change everything. Anyway, take a look at APD docs, it's a great tool!